# Setting up assets paths for webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

Lost another day by figuring out how to set up webpack-dev-server **with hot reload**. I would like to serve my JS and CSS assets in `index.html` with following paths: `/dist/js/app.min.js` and `/dist/css/styles.min.css`.

How the hell I am suppose to configurate `webpack.config.js` to load my assests in `index.html` with correct paths mentioned above? With current configuration webpack-dev-server is holding my build inside `/dist` folder only and in index.html I have to set paths without js or css folder, e.g.: (`<script src="/dist/app.min.js" />`).

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/js'),
    filename: 'app.min.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

My project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the HtmlWebpackPlugin? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

This is my setup:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: project.paths.client('index.html'), // absolute url to index.html
  hash: false,
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body',
})
```

This will take your entry(ies) and inject them into your index.html

Comment: I tried this plugin, but it is putting index.html inside dist/js folder. If I edit location where index.html will be rendered, then webpack-dev-server serves my template index.html. Another thing, when I want to build for prod with ExtractTextWebpackPlugin, it wont add any CSS link, so I need to specify that link in my index.html template, but then webpack-dev-server wont work as expected.